# Bad math environment delimiter in standalone class

Tags: math-mode, errors, standalone

Given a file `master.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}
\input{sub}
\end{document}
```

and a file `sub.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
\[
        0
\]
\end{document}
```

the command `pdflatex master.tex` runs as expected, but the command `pdflatex sub.tex` gives the error

> Bad math environment delimiter.

Can anyone explain what is going on and/or how to solve this?

Comment: I agree about the possible duplicate. This question can be closed. Or should I delete it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Standalone` is not meant to be used with the environments `displaymath` or `equation` as it would not know, where to put the labelling number. You should do it the following way.

```
% arara: pdflatex 

\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle
        0
$
\end{document}
```

If you want to mimic a real document equation, you should use the `prewiev` option of the `standalone` class.

Comment: The preview option seems to be what I need.